# Function error when loaded, not when pasted

Tags: r, data.table

I built a function that uses a version of `dt_aggregate` package where I only changed a print string.

When I paste function in the console it works, when I load it from the package I've built it return an error.

I can't figure this out.

```
tabellacon777 <- function(x){
  require(data.table)
  require(dplyr)
  source("C:/Users/Utente/Documents/prelievi/R/dt_aggregate.R")
  require(gridExtra)
  require(knitr)
  require(kableExtra)
  divper777 <- x %>%  mutate(Tipo_Marchio = ifelse(Stagione!="P8", "Resi", ifelse(Magazzino.Logico!="77" & Magazzino.Fisico!="06", "FROM", ifelse(Magazzino.Logico=="77","Prima Linea 777","Prima Linea STD"))))      
  resultcon777 <- dt_aggregate(
    divper777, by=.(Tipo_Marchio), by_all.(Tipo_Marchio), 
    NumCapi = sum(Quantità),
    NumPrelievi = sum(complete.cases(Quantità)),
    MedCapiPre = round(mean(Quantità),1),
    OreDecimali = round(sum(ORE_DEC),1),
    CapiOra = round((sum(Quantità)/sum(ORE_DEC)),0),
    PrelieviOra = round((sum(complete.cases(Quantità))/sum(ORE_DEC)),0)
  )
  options(knitr.table.format = "html")
  kable(resultcon777, "html")
  resultcon777 %>%
    kable("html") %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover","condensed"),full_width = F) %>%
    row_spec(5, bold = T, background = "#E3E3E3")

}
```

This is the `dt_aggregate` function:

```
dt_aggregate=function(d, by, by_all,...){

  library(data.table)

  my_args=substitute(.(...))

  my_dims=as.character(substitute(by))
  my_dims=my_dims[2:length(my_dims)]    

  my_dims_d=as.character(substitute(by_all))
  my_dims_d=my_dims_d[2:length(my_dims_d)]

  print(my_dims)
  print(my_dims_d)


  funct_comb=function(d,num){unlist(lapply(seq(nrow(d)),function(x){paste(as.character(d[x,num]),collapse="")}))}

  eg=lapply(1:(length(my_dims_d)),function(x){c(my_dims_d,"[blank]")})
  comb=expand.grid(eg,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  comb$x=funct_comb(comb,seq(length(my_dims_d)))    
  comb=comb[grepl("\\[blank\\]",comb$x),]   
  comb=as.data.frame(lapply(seq(length(my_dims_d)),function(x){dat=comb[,x];dat[dat %in% c("[blank]",my_dims_d[x])]}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  names(comb)=my_dims_d
  comb=comb[!duplicated(funct_comb(comb,seq(length(my_dims_d)))),]

  if(class(comb)=="character"){comb=data.frame(my_dims_d=comb,stringsAsFactors=FALSE);names(comb)=my_dims_d}

  comb=rbind(my_dims_d,comb)
  comb=comb[rev(order(funct_comb(comb,seq(length(my_dims_d))))),,drop=FALSE]
  rownames(comb)=NULL

  non_part=as.data.frame(lapply(my_dims[!(my_dims %in% my_dims_d)],function(x){rep(x,nrow(comb))}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  if(nrow(non_part)>0){
    names(non_part)=non_part[1,]
    comb=cbind(comb,non_part)
  }

  l=list()
  d=as.data.table(d)
  for(i in 1:nrow(comb)){
    dims_to_run=as.character(comb[i,])

    dims_to_run_i=dims_to_run[!is.na(match(names(comb),dims_to_run))]
    dims_to_run_e=names(comb)[is.na(match(names(comb),dims_to_run))]

    if(length(dims_to_run_i)>0){        
      dims_to_run_ev=paste0(".(",paste(dims_to_run_i,collapse=","),")")
      print(dims_to_run_ev)             
      eval(parse(text=paste0("dd=d[,eval(my_args),by=",dims_to_run_ev,"]")))
    }else{
      dd=d[,eval(my_args)]                      
    }

    if(length(dims_to_run_e)>0){    
      all_df=as.data.frame(lapply(dims_to_run_e,function(x){rep(paste0("Totali"),nrow(dd))}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      names(all_df)=dims_to_run_e
      dd=cbind.data.frame(dd,all_df)
    }

    l[[length(l)+1]]=dd         
  }


  rbindlist(l, use.names=TRUE)


}
```

When I paste `tabellacon777` function in console everything goes OK.
When I load library with `tabellacon777` function inside, then run the function it says:

```
[1] "Tipo_Marchio"
[1] "Tipo_Marchio"
[1] ".(Tipo_Marchio)"

 Error in .(NumCapi = sum(Quantità), NumPrelievi = sum(complete.cases(Quantità)),  : 
  could not find function "."
```

Comment: A call to `library` has no place in a package. I assume you have not created the correct DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files. You might need to study some documentation and tutorials.

Comment: the dt_aggregate function that has the call to library isn't mine and when I load it this way: source(file=url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kirillsavine/data_handling/master/dt_aggregate.r")) it works, but I slightly modified it (just a "string")

Comment: after learning how to build a R package as mentioned by Roland, you can check out https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/doc/datatable-importing.html to fix that particular `could not find function "."` issue